# monetdb - error loading tbl

Tags: database, loading, monetdb

Loading the .tbl file I've got this error:

```
[nicola@localhost ~]$ mclient -d dbmonet  -s  "COPY  INTO  monet.SUPPLIER  FROM  STDIN  USING  DELIMITERS ',','\\n','\"'" - < /home/nicola/Scrivania/tabellemonetdb/supplier.tbl
user(nicola):monetdb
password:
missing separator ',' line 0 expecting 6 got 1  fields
failed to import table
current transaction is aborted (please ROLLBACK)
syntax error, unexpected sqlINT in: "0201"
```

Why do I get this error?
I'm using an ssb schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about the structure of the supplier.tbl file, my guess (from having used SSBM before) would be that it does not use "," as a field separator, but "|".

My SSBM loading command for the supplier table looks like this:

```
COPY INTO SUPPLIER FROM '/path/to/supplier.tbl' USING DELIMITERS '|', '|\n' LOCKED;
```

Comment: when I create table in monetdb, right?
Another thing: I've generated tables data with ssb-dbgen-master, I've edited makefile in this way:
    DATABASE= MONETDB
    MACHINE = LINUX 
    WORKLOAD = SSBM
and in tpcd.h I added these rows:
#ifdef MONETDB
#define GEN_QUERY_PLAN  "EXPLAIN"
#define START_TRAN      "BEGIN TRANSACTION"
#define END_TRAN        "END TRANSACTION"
#define SET_OUTPUT      ".SET FORMAT OFF\n.EXPORT REPORT file="
#define SET_ROWCOUNT    ".SET RETCANCEL ON\n.SET RETLIMIT %d\n"
#define SET_DBASE       ".LOGON %s\n"
#endif
Then I use make and generate data...it's right?

Comment: In my setup, I simply set the values in makefile to
    DATABASE=DB2
    MACHINE=LINUX
    WORKLOAD=SSBM
That should be enough.